# Is this topology bad?

Tags: topology

[image]

I don't know how to manage topology properly and barely know anything about it, but I don't think this is too bad? And if it is bad is there any way I can improve this?

Comment: it's a bit dense imho, unless you can't use any Subdivision Surface modifier? Also, in some parts, you could reduce the amount of faces

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Red zones - too dense
Blue zones - stretched topology and n-gons

Try to maintain constant density as much as you can. Ideal polygon is not just quad but a square. I suggest you read this https://topologyguides.com/

Comment: Is this any better? https://ibb.co/4FZXrLr

Comment: you have dissolved some edges which has fixed the density problem but left you with n-gons. You need to find a way to make them all quads. It's hard to edit model which was created without proper topology in mind. You may want to practice more, find a strategy that suits best and start from scratch. Here is a quick fix attempt https://imgur.com/a/jd9NRM2